# Magento Product Image default value for sort order

Tags: php, image, sorting, product, magento-1.9

I am having trouble with the sort order of my product images, since the website I am working on uses 4 different languages, every time a translator registers a new version of the product the images need to be manually sorted all over again.

My question is - Is there a way to force the default order of Images to be the one that is under Default Values store view, so that all other store views have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Changing the value inside myproduct.js from `this.images[index].position` to `this.images[index].position_default`. This makes the default value always take priority over the other store view values, so be aware. Hope this helps someone with similar issues.